# How to decompress file encrypt lua

Tags: decompress, lua

I recently decrypted a mobile game, after decrypting xxtea and luajit I got strange encryption file, it was an extra layer of encryption before finding the original .lua file content. I'm very confused because I haven't encountered this type of encryption before, please help confirm the encryption type through the attached file.
https://www.mediafire.com/file/zxbrsoc2qn97rs6/config.skill_enc/file
[image: file content encrypt]

So file:
https://www.mediafire.com/file/uvgq0v90w78himf/libcocos2dlua.so/file

Apk: https://www.mediafire.com/file/sw636d3iqtmnbqq/luagame.apk/file

Comment: If that's an xxtea-decrypted file then the decrypting process for its contents probably happens in one of the .lua files rather than in the .so binary; you should share the decrypted files, too.

Comment: please do not  post a picture of text ... post the text instead

Comment: @jsotola Sorry for the inconvenience, as the content of the file is too long to post, so please download the attachment: https://www.mediafire.com/file/zxbrsoc2qn97rs6/config.skill_enc/file

Comment: what are you talking about? ... it's only two lines of text in the picture ... it is not easily readable

Comment: @jsotola that's an illustration, you can download the text file to see the full content, I've attached the text file download link above

Comment: @user7290573 luadLoadBuffer did not load this file

Comment: There exist second decryption step, probably some Lua code (a decryptor) decrypts this long string into Lua program and run it.